# Why randomly today I am blocked from phpmyadmin with a #2002 error?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, config

Today I was starting up XAMPP on mac osx mavericks. MySQL did not start. Apache did.
I try to visit phpmyadmin and get this error:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Could anyone give me directions as to whats going on? 
Any questions please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It is relevant enough.

Comment: In what way?  This is an environment issue.

Comment: if you don't know the answer I apologise. No need to make excuses. Leave.